# Can't add reference to my ASP.NET web-service on GoDaddy

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx

I tried to publish an asmx web service to GoDaddy, and then consume it from a console application.

So I managed to publish it to my GoDaddy domain via FTP. When adding a Service Reference to the .asmx file, I get the following error.

How can this be solved?

> The document at the url http://www.myDomain.com/myFolder/Service1.asmx was not recognized as a known document type.
>       The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:
>       - Report from 'XML Schema' is 'Name cannot begin with the '%' character, hexadecimal value 0x25. Line 1, position 2.'.
>       - Report from 'DISCO Document' is 'Name cannot begin with the '%' character, hexadecimal value 0x25. Line 1, position 2.'.
>       - Report from 'WSDL Document' is 'There is an error in XML document (1, 2).'.
>       - Name cannot begin with the '%' character, hexadecimal value 0x25. Line 1, position 2.
>       Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://www.myDomain.com/myFolder/Service1.asmx'.
>       The content type text/plain of the response message does not match the content type of the binding 
>       (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the 
>       IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 93 bytes of the response were:
>        '<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="Service1.asmx.cs" Class="MyFirstAsmx.Service1" %>'.
>       If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure your service is in an ASP.NET enabled "site" first.

The error says the web server is serving the page's code directly and not executing the code.

Comment: does it have to be? All i want is a service that can return values for specific calls, I don't need full asp.net site.

Comment: @seren You must. It's returning verbatim the content in the asmx file. It's a simple tweak of an IIS setting.

Comment: @seren1ty you don't need a "full asp.net site" when you enable an ASP.NET application in IIS. You do need the application setup in IIS to have ASP.NET though, otherwise the server has no clue what to do with the code (server instructions).

Comment: thanks for the quick replies, and sorry for another dumb question...
I have received this godaddy account from a friend - which says this is the hosting type:
OS/Hosting Type: Linux / 4GH Web Hosting.

does it mean i cannot run asp.net on this server?

Comment: @seren1ty That is correct. GoDaddy doesn't support ASP.NET on their linux hosting.